# Changing Label from textbox input

Tags: c#, winforms

```
namespace HospitalMonitor
{
    public partial class PatientRegister : Form
    {
        public PatientRegister()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtPatientName.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You did not enter anything, please enter the patients name.");
            }
            else
            {
                CentralStation.centralModule1.lblPatientName = txtPatientName.Text;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is what is causing the error.

```
CentralStation.centralModule1.lblPatientName = txtPatientName.Text;
```

This is the code that I have, I am trying to get it to register the textbox input and when the button is pressed have it rename a label that is in a different form. This label is from a usercontrol that I have made myself and imported onto the form 'CentralStation'. I am however getting the error:

> CS0120 - An Object reference is required for the non-static field,
>   method or property 'CentralStation.centralModule1'.

I do not have the understanding myself to think of a possible solution to this I believe. I have looked around and still don't get it.

I hope you understand what I am trying to do!

This is how I am hiding the forms.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace HospitalMonitor
{
    public partial class CentralStation : Form
    {
        public CentralStation()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            PopulateCentralStationBedsideDetails();
        }

        public void PopulateCentralStationBedsideDetails()
        {
            centralModule1.lblBedNumber.Text = "Bed 1";
            centralModule2.lblBedNumber.Text = "Bed 2";
            centralModule3.lblBedNumber.Text = "Bed 3";
            centralModule4.lblBedNumber.Text = "Bed 4";
            centralModule5.lblBedNumber.Text = "Bed 5";
            centralModule6.lblBedNumber.Text = "Bed 6";
            centralModule7.lblBedNumber.Text = "Bed 7";
            centralModule8.lblBedNumber.Text = "Bed 8";
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Hide();
            BedsideMonitor bedsideMonitor = new BedsideMonitor();
            bedsideMonitor.ShowDialog();
            this.Visible = false;
            Show();
        }

        private void btnRegBed1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Hide();
            PatientRegister patientRegister = new PatientRegister();
            patientRegister.ShowDialog();
            this.Visible = false;
            Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need an instance of CentralStation form to change the label inside your UserControl. This is a fundamental aspect of object oriented programmming. CentralStation is the name of a class not an object created from that class (one of many instances that you could create with the new keyword.).

Comment: You should create an instance of CentralStation class.

Comment: Okay I will try that now, I am trying to get back into C# clearly I have forgotten a big basic aspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Something like...

```
private void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtPatientName.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You did not enter anything, please enter the patients name.");
    }
    else
    {
        //do something to get reference to your form...
        //for example, you can create a new form, or get the form by its id
        CentralStation centralStation = new CentralStation();
        centralStation.centralModule1.lblPatientName = txtPatientName.Text;
        //and then do something else...
        centralStation.Show();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

In response to "How to get reference", you can pass the CentralStation into the PatientRegister.

For example, in your CentralStation class,

```
private void btnRegBed1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Hide();
        //here you pass your CentralStation into the patientRegister you are initiating by using "this"
        PatientRegister patientRegister = new PatientRegister(this);
        patientRegister.ShowDialog();
        this.Visible = false;
        Show();
    }
```

and in your PatientRegister class,

```
public partial class PatientRegister : Form
{

    private CentralStation centralStation;

    public PatientRegister(CentralStation cs)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //here you get the reference of the centralStation 
        this.centralStation = cs;
    }


    private void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtPatientName.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You did not enter anything, please enter the patients name.");
        }
        else
        {
            // this.centralStation is the one you have hidden
            this.centralStation.centralModule1.lblPatientName = txtPatientName.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I go about referencing the one that I have hidden? I have checked the code you have put. I just dont want to open up a completely new one.

Comment: If you could hide the form, you already have the reference to it. How did you hide it in the first place?